# issue in time format

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am receiving Date in correct format but there is issue in Time, Which is not in correct format.

My Output is :- 2018-08-21 00:00:00.000

Here is my code:-

```
myConn.Open();
string query1 = "insert into [LoginLog] ([User_id],[LoginDate]) values ('" + username + "','" + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString() + "' ) ";
SqlCommand cmdUpdate = new SqlCommand(query1, myConn);
cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
myConn.Close();
```

Comment: Do not concat SQL. What in your snippet is "receiving" a date and what do you consider your "output"? What would be your desired output?

Comment: Use parameters in your query.

Comment: @Fildor my output will be like this :-    08/15/2018 7:48:59 AM

Comment: Use Localization Concept to solve this issue.

Comment: It's unclear whether you mean that the value isn't stored correctly in the database, or whether you're unable to display it properly when fetching it later. I would *strongly* advise you to use parameterized queries though, at which point you wouldn't be converting `DateTime.UtcNow` to a string at all in this code.

Comment: @DaisyShipton ok

Comment: How you need to shape a date/time strongly depends on how it is represented in the DB. So please also tell us, of what type is the Column "LoginDate" ?

Comment: @Fildor it is of datetime datatype

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using a predefined format because in every computer the result of `DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()` will be different,  because of time-zones and how the current DateTime format of the computer is defined

you can do something like this

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: The OP is trying to insert the value into a database, with a field of type datetime. The best solution is not to use a string representation at all, but to use parameterized SQL and specify the value as a parameter, still using `DateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

The method ToString of datetime have a string parameter to change de format, you can consult in this link

Try to use this format `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt`

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1